# Is it possible to change the ActionBar Colour in android?

Tags: android, menu, colors, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have been searching the net and so far either no solution or a very lengthy process.

All I want to be able to do is change the colour of my action bar and the menu that pops down to red.

I do not want to change anything else.

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me a way to do it, if there is one.

Thanks

Comment: I tried that yesterday, it seemed pretty long and it messed up my project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can but, you have to modify your resources, try the following link:

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

The above link is used to edit actionbar colors and menu colors. Just you have to pick the colors and styles. after choosing just download the files and place in your project. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.. See this page will help you..

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in you application theme.

This is what I had pre lollipop.

in `styles.xml`

```
<resources>
    <color name="WhiteColor">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="DarkBlueColor">#0085C3</color>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>        
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/DarkBlueColor</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleStyle</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_action_nav_icon</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTitleStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/WhiteColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

in your `manifest.xml` make sure your app uses your personal theme

```
<application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
...
</application>
```

Comment: Where does android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > go, I have permissions added between application and adding this line turns it black.

Comment: I figured that out, its not leting me run, I get this error error: Tag <style> can not appear inside <style>, only <item>

Comment: looks like you put a <style> in a <style>, I editted my post to add the parent <ressource> tag in styles.xml file

Comment: Hi, I sorry I am not experienced about this, I assume this is to do with the colour. I am getting this error. error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:background' with value '@color/DarkBlueColor').

Comment: I edited again. You can see how to set your own colors.

Comment: Now this error comes error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:icon' with value '@drawable/ic_action_nav_icon').

Comment: This is where you can set your own icon. Just remove that line for now.

Comment: Hi thanks, this works. is it possible to change the menu colour as well, that is black atm.

Comment: This would be another question.

Comment: Should I start another thread for this? could you please answer it for me.

Comment: If you want to also style the menu, you will probably have to use the tool that `@No Name` mentioned. Btw, Actionbar is now deprecated with lollipop. If you start a brand new app you might want to take a look at the toolbar widget. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html